# User can't search on a particular field while other users can

Tags: security, custom-field, search, global-search

I have a user that is unable to search (sidebar) on an auto-number field on a custom object.  The field does have a master-detail relationship with an account, however this user has read all access to both accounts and the custom object.  I checked the field level security and everyone in our organization has read access to the field.

When I search on the auto-number field I get results back.  When he searches on the auto-number field he can't see the record.

What's getting in the way of that record being returned in search results?

Comment: Seems like you have all the usual bases covered but just to make sure have you checked 'Field Accessibility' under setup? I'm assuming this user/profile has no problem viewing and reporting on either object.

Comment: The field accessibility shows the field as read-only.

Comment: Another stupid question, you have logged in as this person and tried the search?

Comment: Does the user have access to the "Tab" for that object. If they do not then no search result will appear

Comment: @Eric - I just discovered that last night!  It seems silly to have a tab UI setting control search results.  If you want to post that as the answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for Objects (Records) to be included int he search results the user must have access to the Object Tab. Check to ensure that the user has access to the tab and run the search again.